# How to automate Visual Studio 2017 web project publish to folder

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, webdeploy

I am trying to create a PowerShell v5 script to build and publish a VS2017 WCF Web Service Application (.NET Framework 4) so that I can automate it in Bamboo. I have the msbuild command working that does the build correctly and now I need to publish the project to a folder using a FolderProfile.

I can do it manually with success by right-clicking on the project and selecting publish, then selecting the FolderProfile. This puts the files that need to be deployed to the website in the project's bin\Release\PublishOutput location. I want to automate that publishaction in a Powershell script.

I have tried the recommendation on [Sayed Hashimi's](http://sedodream.com/2013/01/06/CommandLineWebProjectPublishing.aspx) site, which is similar to below (I just use VS2017 version of 15.2, and, of course, replace the project name and profile with my actual values);

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name> /p:Password=<insert-password> /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.2
```

But this did not put any files in the `bin\Release\PublishOutput` location. It looked like it just did a standard build.

**EDIT:**

msbuild lists this line in the output when I run the above command;

```
DeploymentUnpublishable:
    Skipping unpublishable project.
```

I have looked through [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901) post on GitHub and some have cited a solution as updating to v15.2 of VS2017, which I have already done;

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.2 (26430.16) Release
```

Any Ideas?

**EDIT - Solution**

@Leo-MSFT provided this solution...

```
msbuild myproject\myproject.vbproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml /p:Configuration=Release
```

This put the files into bin\release\PublishOutput.

I had spent several days searching for this solution and I had added various command parameters suggested in other SO and GitHub forum posts, such as `/t:Publish`, `/p:PublishProfileRootFolder` and `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.2`. I removed those and just used the line above which finally created the published output I needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> this did not put any files in the bin\Release\PublishOutput location. It looked like it just did a standard build

I have reproduced this issue with your command line. After research this issue for a long time, I try to remove the parameter "`/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.2`", then re-publish the project with the command line:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="MyProfile.pubxml"
```

It build and publish successfully, and web project publish to folder where you set in the option "`<publishUrl>`" in MyProfile.pubxml.

So please try to remove the parameter **"/p:VisualStudioVersion**" in the MSBuild command line, check if it works for you.

Note: I have also test that command line with VisualStudioVersion for the project created by the Visual Studio 2015, it works fine. Not sure whether this is a issue for Visual Studio 2017, I need to confirm it, if it`s a issue for Visual Studio 2017, I will send this issue to Visual Studio team.

Comment: This solved the issue perfectly. My final command line ended up as msbuild myproject\myproject.vbproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml /p:Configuration=Release. This put the files into bin\release\PublishOutput. Thanks

Comment: This also solved my issue (in addition to using the right msbuild). With previous versions of VS I used to call C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe and provide the /p:VisualStudioVersion parameter. Now with VS 2017 Community I call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" without the VisualStudioVersion parameter, and it works

Comment: this doesn't take care of web.config 
Transform